# Windows XP - Windows 7 remote assistance compatibility

Tags: windows-7, remote-access

I run Windows XP and my mother is getting a new PC with Windows 7.  We go remote quite frequently using Windows Messenger Remote Assistance. Will we still be able to do this when she gets the new PC?

Comment: I can't. It seems that Windows 7 RA is faulty & will not connect to an XP computer. There are a number of others with similar problems

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/302890/remote-assistance-to-windows-7-starter-permission-denied/370459#370459 and http://superuser.com/questions/149539/i-cant-do-a-remote-assistance-session-to-a-windows-xp-box-from-windows-7/370457#370457 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Or you can try Teamviewer instead :)

Comment: Fogh, is this from experience using it or do you have a source?

Comment: Teamviewer is highly recommended on most all help forums.
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=teamviewer+review&aq=f&aqi=g5g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CUvp1Jis3TJCxGorAM6CPoYEKAAAAqgQFT9AJX0k&gs_upl=312%2C312%2C1%2C0%2C61%2C61%2C1&fp=36ec6be010d257f