# I can't do a Remote Assistance session to a Windows XP box from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, connection, firewall, remote-assistance

My Mom's computer is running Windows XP, and my desktop running Windows 7. She's having some technical issue, so I want to do a Remote Assistance session to her machine. However, no matter what I've tried, the Remote Assistance program doesn't connect successfully. I've verified that the Windows Firewall (on both my and her machines) is configured properly to allow Remote Assistance program to go through.

What's interesting is that I have the same problem when I try to do Remote Assistance from my desktop to my laptop, which is also running Windows XP. However, when I try to connect to my girlfriend's machine, which is runninng Windows 7 this time, the connection is successful.

So in the end, I guess there must be some incompability between Windows 7 and Windows XP. Does anyone experience the same issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: Can't you initiate the Remote Assistance session through MSN?

Comment: I initiated the Remote Assistance through both Control Panel UI and Widnows Live Messenger. Both failed with the same behavior.

Comment: Maybe you can run sfc /scannow to check if any of the files are broken. I believe R.A. is included with Windows, so it should catch any kind of corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Windows 7 machine, get the user to open Remote Assistance and send you an invitation for help, by email. For some reason, this seems to work where a direct offer of assistance from XP to Windows 7 does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get a remote assistance session going and you're willing to sidestep the immediate issue with Remote Desktop Connection, I'd suggest trying the free version of [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/download/index.aspx) (you load the full - but still free - version; she loads the Quick Support version).  I know how un-satisfying it can be to not know some why something is broken, but this can get the support going while you work on fixing the issue with RDC.

Comment: Hi, it is not the issue with Remote Desktop. The issue is with Remote Assitance.

Comment: @super Remote Assistance uses the remote desktop protocol (rdp)